# Windows 11 PC printing two pages to one sheet irrespective of settings

Tags: printing, windows-11, network-printer

A Windows PC is insisting on printing two pages to one sheet on a network-attached Brother printer. I want to stop it doing this.

Problem only occurs with this specific PC and printer combination - printing from the PC to another printer gives one page per sheet output, and printing from other devices to the Brother printer is similarly normal. Problem occurs in all applications (that I know of) on the PC, including Window's test page print feature. It occurs in apps like Word even when I explicitly select single page per sheet printing in Word's print dialog. Because the problem only occurs on one PC, I don't think the problem is with the printer. Because it appears to happen with all applications on the PC, I don't think it's application-specific.

I've tried removing the printer from the PC's settings, and then removing the cached driver using Control Panel -> Print Manager. I've scoured the system print properties/settings dialogs for relevant system-level printer settings. Looking for suggestions for what to try next.

PC: Windows 11 Pro x64 version 22H2.
Printer: Brother MFC-J5625DW connected via wifi

Thanks